# no puedo cambiar de version de node con nvm

Tags: nodejs, nvm

Tengo instaladas varias versiones de node, cuando coloco "nvm use" con la version que quiero utilizar, si hace el cambio pero cuando coloco "node -v", no me refleja el cambio, si me pudieran ayudar por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya tenías node instalado anteriormente? Ejecuta el comando `where node` para saber dónde está el ejecutable que encontró y agrega ese dato a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Mateo, si ya cuento con node, ahi te muestro que ya ejecute where node

Comment: Es probable que ese sea el problema. Borra las versiones de node que tenías antes y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Las variables de entorno?

Comment: Agregue imagenes de lo que he estado modificando, pero sigo con el mismo resultado